# How to compute the inverse CDF of HyperbolicDistribution properly?

Tags: numerics, bugs, probability-or-statistics, version-8, distributions

Fixed in version 9.

---

I want to compute the CDF and inverse CDF of the hyperbolic distribution:

```
α = 2; β = 3/2;
x = -3;
u = N[CDF[HyperbolicDistribution[α, β, 1, 0], x], 30]
```

The output of the above code is

```
5.36058384200167863956651004148*10^-6
```

A small, but not too small number. Now, since the CDF and inverse CDF are compositional inverses, I expect the output from the following line to be approximately $-3$:

```
xA = N[InverseCDF[HyperbolicDistribution[α, β, 1, 0], u], 30]
```

But *Mathematica* instead returns

```
-23.0838707895835608942828900958
```

which is just way off. So, am I doing something wrong here? Or are *Mathematica*'s `CDF[]` and `InverseCDF[]` functions not to be trusted for this distribution?

When the above experiment is repeated with the normal distribution, there are no problems:

```
x = -12;
u = N[CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], 30]
xA = N[InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], u], 30]
```

The output is $-12$, as expected.

Comment: Looks like something wonky in the numerical evaluation... I'll note that `Quantile[]` also returns the same erroneous value.

Comment: @J. M. I have a suspicion this is a bug in Mathemica, I have observed this inconsistency with the cdf and quantile for other distributions also. StudentT works as expected though

Comment: @aukie looks like a bug. Works for x=-1 or 1 though.

Comment: @aukie This bug has been fixed. It would be helpful if you could provide additional instances of incorrect behavior you mention you encountered and sent them to `support@wolfram.com`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One hack-ish method for evaluating an inverse CDF is to use the [event location](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveEventLocator.html) functionality of `NDSolve[]`. As an example:

```
dist = HyperbolicDistribution[2, 3/2, 1, 0];
c0 = N[CDF[dist, 0], 20]
   0.058032099055437685722
```

Suppose that we want to evaluate the inverse CDF for this particular hyperbolic distribution at the $p$-value $7\times10^{-6}$. Since this value is smaller than `c0`, we integrate the ODE for the CDF,

$$c^\prime(x)=\mathtt{PDF[dist},\;x\mathtt{]},\quad c^\prime(0)=\mathtt{c0}$$

backwards, like so:

```
With[{p = 7*^-6}, 
     x0 = Extract[c["Domain"] /. 
                  First @ NDSolve[{c'[u] == PDF[dist, u], c[0] == c0}, c, {u, -Infinity, 0},
                                  AccuracyGoal -> Infinity,
                                  Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> c[u] == p,
                                             Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"}], {1, 1}]]
   -2.9217514743315895
```

However, the value thus returned is not sufficiently accurate:

```
CDF[dist, x0]
   7.00002*10^-6
```

The cure is easy: treat `x0` as a starting value for further polishing with Newton-Raphson:

```
With[{p = 7*^-6}, 
     xx = FixedPoint[(# - (CDF[dist, #] - p)/PDF[dist, #]) &, x0]]
   -2.9217521320606825
```

which gives a much better result:

```
CDF[dist, xx]
   7.*10^-6
```

If one wanted to evaluate the inverse CDF for values greater than `c0`, one should of course integrate forward (that is, change the integration interval to `{u, 0, Infinity}`) and then extract the right end of the `"Domain"` of the `InterpolatingFunction[]` (using, say, `Extract[(* stuff *), {1, 2}]`).

---

Another ODE-based method that can be used is based on the usual formula for the derivative of an inverse function:

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f^{(-1)}(x)=\frac1{f^\prime(f^{(-1)}(x))}$$

which can be treated as an ODE for the *inverse* CDF. For the case of the hyperbolic distribution, Leobacher and Pillichshammer, in [their paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00607-002-1465-x), suggest the use of the initial condition

$$f^{(-1)}(\mathtt{CDF[HyperbolicDistribution[}\alpha,\beta,\delta,\mu\mathtt{]},x_0\mathtt{]})=x_0,\qquad x_0=\mu+\frac{\beta\delta}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}$$

Here's a *Mathematica* demonstration of this strategy, using the $p$-value $2\times10^{-8}$:

```
dist = HyperbolicDistribution[2, 3/2, 1, 0];
With[{α = 2, β = 3/2, δ = 1, μ = 0}, xs = N[μ + β δ/Sqrt[α^2 - β^2], 25]];
cs = CDF[dist, xs];

With[{p = 2*^-8},
     x0 = c[p] /. 
          First @ NDSolve[{c'[u] == 1/PDF[dist, c[u]], c[cs] == xs}, c, {u, cs, p},
                          AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]]
   -4.630068132899461
```

One can again use Newton-Raphson to further polish the value obtained:

```
With[{p = 2*^-8}, xx = FixedPoint[(# - (CDF[dist, #] - p)/PDF[dist, #]) &, x0]]
   -4.62518360657725
```

This strategy will run into numerical difficulties for $p$-values very near to $0$ or very near to $1$; see the Leobacher/Pillichshammer paper for details on how to proceed in these cases.

---

Encapsulating any of these two strategies into a general procedure is left as an exercise to the interested reader.

Answer (score 1):

Works with version 9.0.1.0 even without higher precision

$Version

"9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013)"

```
a = 2; b = 3/2;
x = -3;
u = CDF[HyperbolicDistribution[a, b, 1, 0], x] // N

(* 5.360583842001691*^-6 *)

x == InverseCDF[HyperbolicDistribution[a, b, 1, 0], u]

(* True *)
```