# Generating random numbers from specified distribution under a constraint

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random

I need to generate 500 numbers from a distribution specified. I used the well-known CDF method, but since I'm new to Mathematica, I don't know how to set a condition on the sum of these variables.

```
dist := 
  ProbabilityDistribution[(2/Sqrt[Pi]* Exp[-1/x])/x^(5/2), {x, 0, ∞}];
g[x_] = CDF[dist, x];
h = 
  Table[{g[x], x}, {x, 0, 5500}] // N // Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 5] &;

d = 1; 
While[d < 5990 || d > 6010, 
  h /@ (RandomReal[{0, 1}, {500}]); 
  d = Total[h]]
```

Where, with `Total`, I'm trying to obtain the sum of the interpolated array but for some reason it gives me this error:

> Lists of unequal length in InterpolatingFunction...

Update:

```
d = 1; While[d < 5990 || d > 6010, 
 a = h /@ (RandomReal[{0, 1}, {500}]);
 d = Total[a]]
```

This works. Tahnks anyway for the help.

Comment: To get 500 random numbers from your distribution use `SeedRandom[1234];
 data = RandomVariate[dist, 500];` The `SeedRandom` is needed to give you reproducible results.

Comment: Probably I didn’t explain myself properly: I need 500 values from my distribution conditioned by the value of their sum. For this reason I need a cycle until I have the set I’m looking for.

Comment: Moreover the solution you suggested gives quite different results compared to the one here suggested, which is the one I used https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13981/how-to-generate-a-randomvariate-of-a-custom-distribution

Comment: FWIW, your CDF has a closed form: `2/Sqrt[π t] Exp[-1/t] + Erfc[1/Sqrt[t]]`. You can perhaps try using it in `FindRoot[]` to implement the inverse CDF. Alternatively, you could look into using `NDSolve[]`, as was done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13839).

Answer (score 1):

Your probability distribution has a mean of 2. That means the expected value of 500 random variates will be 1000. Therefore, the following will work:

```
SeedRandom[42]
sample =
  With[{sum = 1000, d = 10},
    Module[{testSum = 1, sample},
      While[testSum < sum - d || testSum > sum + d,
        sample =
          Quiet @ 
            RandomVariate[
              ProbabilityDistribution[
                (2/Sqrt[Pi] Exp[-1/x])/x^(5/2), {x, 0, ∞}], 
                500];
        testSum = Total[sample]];
      sample]];

Short[sample, 4]
```

> `{1.07783, 1.24783, 0.550867, 20.2222, 0.185783 <<491>>, 
>   0.923722, 1.62345, 0.47509, 0.727451}`

```
Total[sample]
```

> `993.243`

However, if you were to raise the value of `sum` to 6000, your chance drawing a sample meeting your requirement would less than the chance of a snowball successfully rolling through hell.

Comment: I suggest you trying the code in the update, it's in fact an interesting phenomenon and it's named "condensation". (The simulation lasts a couple of seconds)